# Rabins Signature Implementation

Tags: ds.algorithms, cr.crypto-security, primes

I am searching for an Implementation for Rabins Algorithm in any language. I've searched but haven't got it anywhere. does anybody have a link ?

Comment: Typically asking for software or implementations are not in the scope of cstheory, so I am not sure if this is on-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

There is an implementation of Rabin-Williams signatures in the crypto++ library.